# Different action on submit of form depending on a variable's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a checkout form which includes a field to enter a coupon code. Currently, the form always posts to a payment merchant. However, I want it to take a different action/route if the amount due is 0 because of the coupon code.

The view page contains:

```
# Form where to enter coupon code
<%= form_for @coupon, method: :post, url: {action: "check_coupon", :controller => 'coupons', format: 'js'}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Coupon" %>
  <%= f.text_field :couponcode, :placeholder => "Enter coupon" %>
  ...hidden fields...
<% end %>

# Form sent to payment merchant
<form action="https://secure.***.com/order.html" method="post" >
  <input type="hidden" name="payment" value="<%=@payment%>" class='js-couponpayment' />
  ...other hidden fields...
</form>
```

The controller method `check_coupon` just validates the coupon and sets some of the variables that exist as hidden fields in the form to be send to the payment merchant. This includes a variable called `@payment` which specifies the sum to be paid. This sum gets updated based on the coupon entered. Ajax is used to display the updated sum on the screen but to keep it secure `check_coupon`, and not the script which is only for the number shown on screen, sets the actual sum to be send to the merchant.

If `@payment` is zero, I would like the second form not to post to the merchant, but instead redirect to `root_path` with a flash message. How can I do this? How can I make the `action` for the second form variable depending on the updated value for `@payment` (preferably using Ruby and not javascript)?

Comment: Does the second form have a submit button? If no, when does the second form gets submitted?

Comment: Yes, both forms have a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't want to update the payment hidden field with Ajax because you think rendering it server-side would be more secure. But, this is not the case AFAIK, because regardless of where you render, if you are still displaying the form and making users submit the form, there is always possibility of end user fiddling with the hidden field values. After all, from wherever you rendered, it will always end up the same HTML. So, security must be coped with other measures such as making an HMAC authenticity hash with a private key.

With the security considered, a pure ruby solutions would be to not use ajax at all. Instead make `check_coupon` action render a completely new page that checks the sum after coupon code and render the updated payment form again if sum > 0, otherwise redirect to root_url with flash.

But above solution costs a full page reload and reduces interactivity(user has to wait for the page reload). If you don't want that, you can make you ajax response send back a script that both updates the payment form and the sum user sees. Keep in mind that, with rails, you can still use ruby to render the payment form server-side. An eg. js response would be

```
$('#container-div-of-payment-form').html(<%= j render("payment_form_partial")%>);
//code to update the sum user sees here
```

Within your payment_form_partial, you can check if the updated sum is zero or not and sets the form url accordingly.

Hope you found this useful.

Comment: Thanks, I hope I fully understand it all: I use Ajax only to display the sum on screen. Someone else coded this Javascript for me; I'm not yet able to code in Javascript, which is also part of the reason I'm looking for a Ruby solution. So Ajax is only used for the visual but is not any part in how the submission of the 2nd form is processed. In the controller (instead of Ajax) the amount is calculated and indeed also a hash is calculated, which the merchant will check against the sum to be paid. So I think security wise, it's set up correctly.

Comment: Is it not possible to change the url of the second form to a controller method, which then determines whether it should post to the merchant or whether it should redirect with flash messsage? That's also an additional step but for the user it's not experienced as a page reload. Or would this mean that all the form's hidden fields would have to be repeated in the controller method, which I guess would make it all pretty cluttered...?

Comment: Sadly if you don't want a full page reload, ajax and javascript is the only way to achieve your desired behaviour. I suggest you lookup how to user ajax javascript response with rails. It's actually very easy. You can even use erb within the js response.
Here is an [excellent tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) about using ajax in rails at railscasts.com.